# Is it wrong to call many times my ObjectEntities in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, service

I have a Windows Service running every ten seconds, in different threads.

This service makes various CRUD operations on a SQL Server 2008 Database onto the same machine.

For each CRUD operation, I put a "using" bracket like this example :

```
public object InsertClient(clsClient c)
{
    using (ClientEntities e = new ClientEntities()) {
        e.Clients.AddObject(c);
    }
}
```

I'm concerned about the efficiency of this operations if there is already another thread interacting with the same table. Is it the right way to do this ?

Furthermore, is there any risk of interthread exception with this method ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depends on how the backing data store handles concurrency. What is an interthread exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not wrong to have multiple object entities as long as you create and dispose it right away.

Here is the general recommendation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738470%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> - When working with long-running object context consider the following:
>
>   - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the object context may grow quickly in memory consumption. This may cause
>     performance issues.
>   - Remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
>   - If an exception caused the object context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
>   - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated grows.
> - When working with Web applications, use an object context instance per request. If you want to track changes in your objects between the
>   tiers, use the self-tracking entities. For more information, see
>   Working with Self-Tracking Entities and Building N-Tier Applications.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use an object context instance per form. This lets you use
>   change tracking functionality that object context provides.

If you are worry about the cost of creating connection every new object entities, since EF relies on the data provider and if the provider is ADO.Net, the [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is enabled by default, unless you disable it in connection string.

Also the metadata is cache globally per application domain, so every new object entities will simply copy the metadata from global cache.

And since EF is not thread-safe, it's recommended to have each object entities in each thread.

> Like much of .NET, the Entity Framework is not thread-safe. This means
> that to use the Entity Framework in multithreaded environments, you
> need to either explicitly keep individual ObjectContexts in separate
> threads, or be very conscientious about locking threads so that you
> don't get collisions. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and exhaustive answer!